# jquery live scroll detection

Tags: jquery, scroll, live

How would I set multiple scroll values? For instance, I want "sub-nav-controls" to switch at a different point than "wrap-nav-slider". However, they're currently both switching at 96. I tried breaking them up, but it breaks the script.

```
var fixed = false;
$(document).live("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 96) {
        if (!fixed) {
            fixed = true;
            $('.setup-page .wrap-nav-slider').addClass('nav-slider-fixed');
            $('.setup-page .sub-nav-controls').addClass('sub-nav-controls-fixed');

        }
    } else {
        if (fixed) {
            fixed = false;
            $('.setup-page .wrap-nav-slider').removeClass('nav-slider-fixed');
            $('.setup-page .sub-nav-controls').removeClass('sub-nav-controls-fixed');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split them into two separate if statements, and use `.hasClass` instead of a boolean variable.

```
$(document).live("scroll", function (e) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 96) {
        $('.setup-page .wrap-nav-slider').addClass('nav-slider-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.setup-page .wrap-nav-slider').removeClass('nav-slider-fixed');
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 202) {
        $('.setup-page .sub-nav-controls').addClass('sub-nav-controls-fixed');
    } else {
        $('.setup-page .sub-nav-controls').removeClass('sub-nav-controls-fixed');
    }
});
```

<sub>disclaimer: there are better ways to do this</sub>

Comment: No need to check hasClass since jQuery will do it on addClass.

Comment: @DGS, thanks.  For some reason I thought it did a simple append to `className`.